# Proving one-to-one with 2 variables

Tags: functions

$f: Z×Z -> Z$ 
where $f(m,n) = 2n -m$

In my class we are taught to solve this by simplifying:

$2n_1 - m_1 = 2n_2 - m_2 $

However, I don't understand how this proves or disproves that $f(m,n) = 2n -m$ is 1-1

Comment: $f(-2,0) = f(0,1) $ so its not 1-1

Comment: @Luis Did you just come up with that or is there a formula to solve it?

Comment: I just did $m=0$ and $n=0$ separatedly and choose values for the other axis.

Comment: @Luis so we are supposed to just plug in values till we come to a contradiction?

Comment: When you are convinced that the function is not 1-1, then yes. At least, it was the first thing I thought and it solved the problem

Comment: @Luis So when you cannot simplify further to $x_1 = x_2$, then you can start to plug in values to disprove?

Comment: Its not that easy. There're a lot of functions that needs another approach in order to prove 1-1. For example, with $e^x +x$ I would use derivatives and its properties

Answer (score 0):

If you fix some of the numbers, you can find the others. For example if $n_1 = 0$, $m_1=-4$ and $m_2=0$ then $n_2=-2$ so $f(0,-4)=f(-2, 0)$. You can find other examples !